# Im getting the error = Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type '[String]' Ive looked everywhere and i can't seem to find the answer

Tags: arrays, swift, string, types

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController
 {

    @IBOutlet var Dishname: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var TEXT: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var recipy: UIView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let secondVC: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController


        secondVC.items = TEXT.text! as? String    //Error

// Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type '[String]'

    }
```

Comment: `if let text = TEXT.text { secondVC.items.append(text) }`.

Comment: Yeah, looks like **SecondViewController.items** is a string array, and you're passing it an optional string. Please post your code for **SecondViewController**. I assume you're initializing **SecondViewController.items**? If so, you can do as @Eendje suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The items variable in SecondViewController is Array  of String, [String] type and you try to assign a String to it rather than insert or append into it.

Comment: The error message should have been a giveaway. And the fact that he is assigning to "items", not "item".